# Stack overflow error c++.How can I modify/repair this code to get rid of this?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I get the stack overflow error/exception(nothing pops up when i search for errors , it's crashing after i run it)  and i don't see what is wrong . Please help . Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int verify(string v, string y[], int m);
int rearrange(string x,string a[],int m)
{
    int TempNumOne = x.size();
    char y[15];
    for (int i = 0; i <= TempNumOne; i++)
    {
        y[i] = x[i];
    }
    next_permutation(y, y + TempNumOne);
    x = y; 
    verify(x, a, m);
    return 0;

}

int verify(string v, string y[], int m)
{
    int z = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        if (v == y[j])
        {
        z++;
        cout << v << endl;
        }
        else
            rearrange(v,y,m); // the code is stoping here and it gives me a "unhandheld exception"

    return z;

}

int main()
{
    int i = 0, n = 0, j = 0, m = 0;
    string x[100];
    string y[2000];
    string a;
    string b;
    ifstream myfile2("wordlist.txt"); 
    fstream myfile("word.txt"); 
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, a)) 
        {
            x[i] = a;
            i++; n++;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file!";

    if (myfile2.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile2, b))
        {
            y[j] = b; 
            j++; m++;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file!";
    myfile.close();
    myfile2.close();
    i = 0;
    while (i <= 15)
    {
        string v = x[i];
        i = verify(v, y, m);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to do a program that gets a number of words from a file(scrambled words) , compare them (1 by 1) with all words from a second file and see if there is a match(by using the "verify" function) , if there is a match show that word to the screen and go to the next one , if not, use the rearrange function to rearrange the letters in the word then use verify function again to see if it gets a match(and so on).What can i do to make this code work , i'm out of ideas.

Later edit : 
I did it with a function to see if the two wordS(one from word.txt and one from wordlist.txt) are anagrams .Here is the function :

```
bool is_anagram(string s1, string s2)
{
    std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    std::sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return s1 == s2;
}
```

Comment: Where is it crashing? With what error? How long are your two files and are you sure they are under 100 and 2000 lines?

Comment: There are too many hard coded numbers in the code. The error could be caused by any of them being too small for the data you are reading from your files.

Comment: Don't hardset arrays of arbitrary size. Use vectors and push back.

Comment: Can't this problem be restated as finding if each string in _words.txt_ is an anagram of one of the strings in _wordlist.txt_? Even if you fix your current code it looks like an extremely inefficient solution.

Comment: Learn using a debugger.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks man , I rewrote the program and used a function to see if the word from words.txt is an anagram of one word from wordlist.txt and it's much easier this way .

Answer (score 1):

You have circular recursions in your `verify()` and `rearrange()` functions without any certain criteria ever ending the recursion. That's like an endless loop, just involving memory allocation on the stack (which is limited).

Format your code properly to see what's going wrong, especially this part

```
int verify(string v, string y[], int m) {
    int z = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { // << open a proper block
        if (v == y[j]) {
            z++;
            cout << v << endl;
        }
        else {
            return rearrange(v,y,m);
         // ^^^^^^ Looks like you're supposed at least to return the recursive 
         //        calls result.
        }
    }
    return z;    
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try to modify both functions and see if I get something but I think I will also try to rewrite it using the sort() function to see if  the word from the first file is an anagram of one of the words from the second file . Thanks all for your comments but ... why the downvotes :\ ...?

Comment: @w0wy _"why the downvotes :\ ...? "_ I'd say merely because of this [last comment's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894512/stack-overflow-error-c-how-can-i-modify-repair-this-code-to-get-rid-of-this/26894790?noredirect=1#comment42345404_26894512) points.

Comment: Mhm , doesn't even matter .... whatever ... anyway thanks to the ones that answered

Comment: @w0wy _"Mhm , doesn't even matter"_ Having received 4 close votes on your question so far, what makes you think learning how to use the debugger is irrelevant to your question?

Comment: The downvotes are irrelevant.